# How to use cursor keys with a modifier to switch buffers in GNU screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to use cursor keys with a modifier like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to switch
between screen buffers (e.g. <kbd>C-a [arrow]</kbd> or <kbd>C-a
C-[arrow]</kbd>). So far I have tried settings like the ones below with
no success.

```
bind     \224\115   prev
bind     \224\116   next

bindkey -d ^[[1;5D  prev
bindkey -d ^[[1;5C  next
```

They are either ignored or behave unexpectedly (the second one). I am
also not sure how to specify the keys. To get the characters, I either
used <kbd>C-v</kbd> to quote them in bash, or tried to look-up on the
Internet (e.g. http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

Any idea how I can achieve this key binding?

**Edit:**

Since I posted the question, I have realised I want cursor keys with a
modifier other wise command line editing for the shell will
break. BugMeNot's answer below answers my old question, but not the
modified one. I have asked this at other places, with no response. For a
summary of my findings so far you can look at
[this](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2012-July/422709.html)
post in the Fedora user's list archives.